# Simplify the gamification further (carpool)

Tags: user-expectation, gamification

I am building a carpool app for India. And the app needs to work on a point (km) system. Initially I thought that working on a system that is based on `points` will be good enough until I was advised to use `kms` instead. So now I am using `kms` for points.

If you drive people around you earn `kms`, if you ride with someone, you spend `kms`.

If you round robin your car, the `kms` rotate within the system. No body looses no body gains at the end of 2 days (assuming only 2 people carpool).

If you only only ride, eventually you will need to buy `kms` from the system.

If you only drive people around, you will need to redeem `kms` in exchange for gifts, coupons and cash.

Now this is my home screen, the question is when you look for the very first time, is the above clear enough ?

[image: app launch]
[image: click on balance, cost, earn toast help]
[image: click driving]

Notice that when I hit **Driving Today**, the action bar and button below changes to **earn** and **Offer Ride**.

## Change made after feedback

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the goal of the app? I'm struggling with understanding why carpoolers that ride are penalized but carpoolers that drive are rewarded. They are both carpooling which I would assume is the objective of a carpooling app.

Comment: If I ride with someone, I need to pay the person driving (pay in km's). And the next day when I drive my car I get paid back. So no profit no loss. But if you dont own a car, or would prefer to be driven daily then you can buy km's from us and continue to drive with someone or the other. I hope I have answered the question. This is in the India context. Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main selling point of the application is the idea. You need to convince your users to this idea, and to do so, you cannot leave them with the bare interface. Instead, you need to **provide a proper onboarding** - but focused on the idea, not interface.

In your mockup, I can see parts of it, but these refer to the features only - I mean this part of it, where I believe these are visual cues you wanted to present to your users:

[image]

Before user lands on this screen, however, s/he needs to see an **explanation what application is about**. You can [go through a lot of onboarding examples on UX Archive](http://uxarchive.com/tasks/onboarding) - hope these will be helpful for you.

Regarding the interface you presented - I think it could be improved in several ways:

- **Switch to user language** - try to use different wording, especially avoid terms like "balance" and "spend". Like "Free kilometers to ride" and "Distance to work".
- **Present multiple values expressed in the same unit as user would read them** (at least when there is relation between them). I mean (available) 100|19 (to spend) is no good, it would be better to use 19|100, as it can be read as "Use 19 out of 100 kilometers"; you can switch to "19 out of 100" completely as well.
- **Provide units** everywhere to avoid confusion (19|100 *km*)
- **Streamline processes** - start the experience with the application from simple selection expressed with two buttons: [I want to give a ride to someone] and [I need a ride] and then let them choose starting/ending locations, dates and times.

Comment: thankyou, I changed my registration page, and my home page based on your answer.